# C# Equalizer app for Windows Sound System

Tags: c#, windows, audio, equalizer

I would like to make an Equalizer app for Windows and apply settings for sound system. I've found many sound API like WASAPI, DirectSound but I don't know if I can use there to apply a filter in real time for all sounds. On C# there is CSCore to manipulate Audio sources but I don't know if I can use it for device.

The other solution is to create a virtual sound device on Windows. It get the actual sound output, transform it with a filter in real time and output this sound. But I don't know where to start to do this. This thing suppose to change to C++ but it is possible in C#?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.